# python function-converting texting language to english?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble creating a function that uses a dictionary of texting abbreviations, and using the dictionary to write functions that translate to and from English. For example: “y r u l8?” translates to “Why are you late?”
So I have this so far: (I don't need every single texting phrase)

```
def text(string):  
    textDict={'y':'why', "l8":'late','u':'you','gtg':'got to go', 'lol': 'laugh out loud', 'ur': 'your',}
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

If you have a dictionary of replacements you can do this:

```
replacements = {
  'lol': 'laugh out loud',
  'y': 'why',
  'l8': 'late',
  'u': 'you',
  'r': 'are'
}

s1 = 'y r u l8'

s2 = ' '.join([replacements.get(w, w) for w in s1.split()])
```

Comment: thnks! i figured out something similar however, the answer comes out without any spacing. how would i add spacing to the returned answer?

Comment: @snwflke00 - Can you explain what you mean by spacing?  Are you referring to line breaks / additional white space?  If so, changing `s1.split()` to `s1.split(' ')` would cause it to only split on spaces, leaving any other white space (new lines, etc) unaffected.  Otherwise, please provide a larger example of the input text.  :)

Comment: @snwflke00: "answer comes out without any spacing": maybe you need `' '.join(....)` instead of `''.join(....)`

Comment: sry! i mean that when the answer is given, it says "whyareyoulate' instead of 'why are you late'

Comment: @snwflke00 - It sounds like you missed the space in `' '.join()`.  You have to indicate what string should be used to connect the members of the returned list.  In this case, a space.

Answer (score 1):

1. string needs to be split into words
2. then loop through each word and replace it with the one in the dictionary if found
3. Then, reconstruct a new string from the words and return it.

str.split() splits into an array, array.join() joins it back.

This won't work if there is punctuation in the sentence.  You would have to detect that and use the word without punctuation as the key

Comment: @g.d.d.c's code is better than what I had -- just look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the text string and if its parts are in textDict and if they are replace them with the contents of the dictionary:

```
def translate(text_string, text_dict):
   for word in text_string.split():
       if word in text_dict:
           text_string = text_string.replace(word, text_dict[word]
  return text_string
```

Comment: This will find words inside of words. For example "toy" will become "towhy"

Comment: Didn't take that into account, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

For something a bit more elaborate try [lookahead-lev](https://github.com/lysdexia/Lookahead-Lev). I made it for a similar situation. Just put your "thumblish" into a yaml file and call it. It's designed to be a web service, but you could probably modify it to suit your needs.